# Writing to log files in a non-blocking manner in Tornado/Python

Tags: python, tornado

I am using Tornado for a websockets server and I am trying to figure out how to log to a file without blocking the main thread. Is tornado.log non-blocking? If not, is there a general pythonic way to log to a file without blocking the main thread?

Thanks!

Comment: You could put the messages in a message queue and write them in another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tornado uses the standard library's `logging` module, which is blocking in most configurations.  Python 3.2 includes a `QueueHandler` class which can be used to move the actual I/O to a separate thread; prior to that there was no standard solution to non-blocking logging (but there's probably a package on PyPI with a 2.x-compatible implementation).